# Secure communication between web server and remote Oracle database using Oracle.DataAccess.Client

Tags: c#, oracle, security, client-server

Our C# Web application connects to a remote oracle database using the Oracle.DataAccess.Client 
I would like to know if the query results are encrypted in transit. I don't see anything the connection string that would indicate that it is an option. Perhaps it is standard, but I don't know.

I need to prepare a document that includes the security considerations of all communications in and out of the system, but am unsure about this one. I appreciate any help with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, database connection and results are not encrypted and secured . You need to turn on SSL (and add other mechanism like access control and monitoring) to keep the connection secure.

Here is how you turn on SSL on Oracle and apply other settings - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28337/tdpsg_network_secure.htm#i1009371

here is a nice discussion on the same topic - 
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14334/when-is-it-appropriate-to-ssl-encrypt-database-connections